# Show that $2-2e^{-|x|}\leq C|x|^{r}$ for some constant $C, r>0$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, real-numbers

I am in the middle of a proof, and I need to show that

> For $x\in\mathbb{R}$, we have  $2-2e^{-|x|}\leq C|x|^{r}$ for some constant $C, r>0$.

The claim can surely be reduced to show that $1-e^{-|x|}\leq C|x|^{r}$  for some $r, C>0$ constant.

However, the problem here is that this inequality can be rewritten as $$1\leq C|x|^{r}+e^{-|x|},$$ but $e^{-|x|}\leq 1$ and is increasing so I need to think about the rate of decreasing of $e^{-|x|}$ and the rate of increasing of $|x|^{r}$.

I use Mathematica to try $C=500$ and $r=1/2$, and it shows that the range is $\geq 1$, so I think the claim is correct.

However, I have no idea about how to prove it.

I tried to compute the derivative, but the derivative is never zero.

Please help! Thank you so much!

**Edit 1: **

Oh I figured it out! We can work with $C=2$ and $r=1$, **mechanodroid** found this result in a easier way. I found it in a hard way...

Below is my proof, using derivative.

Recall that we reduce it to $$1\leq e^{-|t-s|}+ C_{0}|t-s|^{r}\ \text{for some constants}\ C_{0}=C/2, r>0.$$

Consider $C_{0}=1$ and $r=1$ and the function defined by $f(x):=e^{-|x|}+|x|$.

For $x\geq 0$, $f(x)=x+e^{-x}$, and thus $f'(x)=1-e^{-x}$ has solution only at $x=0$, and for $x>0$, $e^{-x}\leq 1$ so $f'(x)=1-e^{-x}\geq 0$, and thus $f(x)$ is increasing in $[0,\infty)$.

For $x\leq 0$, $f(x)=-x+e^{x}$, $f'(x)=-1+e^{x}$ has solution only at $x=0$, and for $x<0$, $e^{x}<1$ so $f'(x)=-1+e^{x}<0$, and thus $f(x)$ is decreasing in $(-\infty,0]$.

Thus, $f(x)$ achieves global min at $x=0$ with minimal value $f(0)=1$.

So $C_{0}=1$, $r=1$ are the desired solution. $C_{0}=1$ means $C=2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $|x| \ge 1$ then since $e^{-|x|} \ge 0$ we have
$$2-2e^{-|x|} \le 2 \le 2|x|.$$
On the other hand, if $|x| \le 1$, then $e^{-|x|} \ge 1-|x|$ so
$$2-2e^{-|x|} \le 2-2(1-|x|) = 2|x|.$$
Therefore we can take $C = 2$ and $r=1$.

Comment: Yeah you are right, I just found it by taking derivative. Thank you!